# What will happen if my implementation of an setXXX method that perform validation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing, kvc

on [Ensuring KVC Compliance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172)
The document says:

Your implementation of the `-set<Key>:` method should not perform validation.
Your class should implement `-validate<Key>:error:` if validation is appropriate for the key.

So will happen if my implementation of an setXXX method that perform validation

Will it cause performance problem when use kvo?

Comment: What does your setter do if the value is not valid?

Comment: it depends on what you means under 'validation', if the caller needs to be notified somehow about the incorrect value, `–validate<key>:error:` should be implemented – if the setter can solve the issue of the invalid values and the caller does not need to be notified because it would be 'too much ado for nothing', the setter can do the job. e.g. the `nil` would not be acceptable as `NSString` the setter can override autoamtically with a `@""`. it is also a type of validation, which is can be solved without involving the caller, but the documetation has to mention this behaviour, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else, if the setter is doing validation (i.e. if it does not set the value if the validation fails), you will end up having KVO notifications informing you of changes, when no changes actually took place. KVO notifications will be posted when you invoke the setter, regardless of whether the setter performs its function successfully or not.